# Outlet in xcode (Newest version)

Tags: ios, xcode, outlet

Well I am a big noob with xcode, and I have a question.  Well basically, I keep watching tuts, about creating a outlet with a web browser or a image view, and all you do is open up the editor and ctrl + click/drag the "image view or web browser" into "view controller H" but every time I open up the editor and click my image or web browser it just goes to in the editor "UIViewConroller.H" and doesnt stay on "ViewController.h". I dont understand why its doing this and every tut i watch or read about, they say do this, and it's not working for me.

Comment: your question is unclear..  but you cam to connect imagview to viewcontroller.xib just declare that with IBOutlet UIWebView *webView and it will show in the file owner just drag the dot on right of webView to the visual webview in viewcontroller.xib

Answer (score 1):

So, in your XCode, I assume you have it setup where you have:

A storyboard
Some sort of ViewControllers inside the storyboard
Some ViewController classes

What you need to do, is you need to make sure that the correct class is referenced inside your specific view controller in the storyboard!

[image]

Then, you will want to make sure that you select the Venn Diagram up top, representing a split view.

[image]

And then you want to make sure your pair window is set to automatic:

[image]

Let me know if it helps! PM Me if not.

Answer (score -1):

You need to select class for your ViewController.
Select the ViewController >Open Utilities > Identity Inspector and make sure that the Class is ViewController